# SMTP/HTTP/FTP status check using PHP

Tags: php, ftp, smtp, status

I am in need of a piece of code to check whether the website is alive or down . I think this can be done with php curl or fsockopen . But i do want to check whether other services like ftp, smtp, https, mysql, etc are up or down . Can anyone tell a method to implement this using php . I have one site to monitor continuously but need a simple script only

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets. Just try to open connection to port you need. If you receiving error - service is down.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php